# What is the exact name of a voice free version of a vocal music?

Tags: instrumental

My main goal is searching in google for some sort of rock musics, I want the best keyword for search.

My question:
What is the name of a voice free version of a vocal music?

Is that instrumental? or is there is a more specific name for it?

Comment: Linked to https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/2852/3260.

Answer (score 4):

You can look for ["Instrumental Version"](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=instrumental+version) or ["Karaoke Version"](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=karaoke+version).

In the reggae world, these tracks, often on the B-side of a 7-inch single, can be referred as ["Version"](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=version), "Dub", or "Riddim".

---

<sub>**off topic**: In case you don't find the song you want, you can try to [remove the voice of your track](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=audacity+remove+voice) (with Audacity for example). You can also check on [Sound SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/).</sub>